# How do I write a linux device driver?

Tags: drivers

Is it difficult for a person who knows average C programming (not CS major) to get started with Linux device drivers development ?but knows assembly programming.so, how one should get started in this case?

Comment: Relevant Q on StackOverflow: [Linux kernel device driver programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11220720/1254292)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the relatively new [Linux Driver Templates](http://elinux.org/Device_drivers). As the name suggests, it provides templates and demonstrates frequently used Linux facilities to get started quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005903) can be good starting point. You can get pdf version of 2nd edition for free.

Comment: "Publication Date: February 14, 2005" for the 3rd edition. Quite some things have changed since then. Can't tell how much, really, but a thing to keep in mind before buying it.